# How to display a nested structure with count of direct and nested children?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, designer

[image]

For Group 1, it has 2 direct children and 4 in total children.
Please suggest if there is a better approach to represent this design as its hard to understand the purpose of count here.
I need this count to be visible directly to the user without performing any action.

Comment: A _tree view_, When multiple selection one might use checkboxes or check marks. Herem with single selection, a single selection style of line highlighting might szffice. Without radio buttons. Check marks are done too.

Comment: Thanks @JoopEggen for your suggestion. But my problem here is with the display of counts besides every group which I have currently handled in 2 brackets. What I am expecting here is a better approach to display these counts be it any structure or selection type. I require that user understands it better in just one look directly.

Comment: There is a _tree table view_ which looks like a tree view and then a table with columns. One could create two columns for the counts. [Example](https://o7planning.org/11149/javafx-treetableview)